# How to change TargetDir in Visual Studio 2017 netcoreapp2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

When I build the netcore 2.0 project, VS2017 generated files in `\bin\DEBUG\netcoreapp2.0\*` rather than in `\bin\DEBUG\*`.

It gives a mirage effect while debugging, since the generated app run as in `\bin\DEBUG\` folder.

So, my config.json file to load should be in `\bin\DEBUG\` folder and so my module folders.

Worse, my modules are netcore project too, and their output folder are in *`\netcoreapp2.0` too.

I find it difficult to copy them manually every time I build the projects.

Is there any way to change TargetDir on netcoreapp2.0? (Without post-build commands)

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, Output path setting.

Comment: It does not work, the compiler always append the TargetDir with \netcoreapp2.0 directory

Answer (score 7):

I managed the issue with adding `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` inside `<PropertyGroup>` tag. It's an old issue due to the lack of interactive window to set .csproj files, so the file should be edited manually.

The first 5 lines of a .csproj file should look like this,

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>     
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```